# css files not getting rendered in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, iis-7.5

I have my project deployed on iis 7.5. 
Now when I try to access it from any other machine in firefox ( in IE its seems to be working fine) , all the files are getting rendered (html, js) except the css files.

By going through the other posts, I have checked that the MIME type for .css files is there in my iis MIME settings.

I am including my css file in my head section as :

```
@Html.CssInclude("jquery.ui.core.css")
```

In the response header, I am getting -
    Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8

I am including my javascript files in the same way:

```
@Html.ScriptInclude("jquery-1.7.min.js")
```

But, in my response headers, I am getting
     Content-Type   application/x-javascript

I am not getting why is the behaviour different for css files.. Please help..

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Yes I had gone through this link, but the answer is valid for Apache server not iis 7.5

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an encoding problem. When you include files with different character encodings browsers can get confused.

Check the encoding of your source files and make sure they are all the same. The easiest way in Windows is to save them as ASCII (with Notepad for example).